# Как установить приложение в папку /home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

У меня почти что забит корень системы /. Как мне поставить приложение в папку /home? Ставлю pycharm через umake ide pycharm. (Я новичок в linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то все правильно, так и должно работать. Вы не сможете изменить путь установки.

В вашей ситуации предлагаю сделать переразметку диска и выделить больше места под нужные разделы